# get all labels and arrows to be readable and evenly distributed

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to `igraph` and can't figure out how to evenly space my labels in order to make them readable:

Given the following vector:

```
 v<-c("ES1-3", "ES4-6", "ES4-6", "ES6-8", "ES6-8", "ES7-9", "ES7-9", 
"ES10-12", "ES10-12", "ES13-15", "ES13-15", "ES16-18", "ES16-18", 
"ES19-21", "ES19-21", "ES22-24", "ES22-24", "ES25-27", "ES25-27", 
"ES28-30", "ES28-30", "ES31-33", "ES31-33", "ES34-36", "ES34-36", 
"ES37-38", "ES13-15", "SA1-3", "SA1-3", "SA4-6", "SA4-6", "SA7-9", 
"SA7-9", "SA10-12", "SA10-12", "SA13-15", "SA13-15", "SA16-18", 
"SA16-18", "SA19-21")
```

My best code to avoid overlapping labels is:

```
g1 <- make_graph( edges=v)

 plot(g1,
 edge.arrow.size=0.5,
 vertex.color='orange',
 vertex.size=7, 
 vertex.frame.color="orange",
 vertex.label.color="black", 
 vertex.label.cex=0.8,
 vertex.label.dist=1,
 edge.curved=T)
```

Resulting in the following graph:

[image]
But notice the arrows that link the edges have different length and the labels are somewhat overlapping the arrows and circles. I really would like to have something neater than this graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for mainly playing with two parameters -

1. **`edge.arrow.size`** - The size of the arrows. Currently this is a constant, so it is the same for every edge. If a vector is submitted then only the first element is used, ie. if this is taken from an edge attribute then only the attribute of the first edge is used for all arrows
2. **`vertex.label.cex`** - The font size for the edge labels

So if you change it to -

```
plot(g1,
     edge.arrow.size=0.3,
     vertex.color='orange',
     vertex.size=7, 
     vertex.frame.color="orange",
     vertex.label.color="black", 
     vertex.label.dist=1,
     vertex.label.cex=0.5,
     edge.curved=T)
```

It becomes a little cleaner -

[image]

Find the full set of parameters [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html)

Comment: could you help me on how to color code the 'SA's' please ???? I would like to give red colors to them.

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  Please ask that as a new question.